# Compute manually random effects variance-covariance matrix terms

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I know that I can get the variance-covariance matrix in R using `VarCorr(model)$grouping.factor` after running a `lme4` model;
but, I would like to understand how to manually obtain each term (except those on diagonal) of anyone of the matrix 
 [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381745/the-correct-random-slope-model-for-nested-data).
Any help in figuring this out is most appreciated.

Thanks